# synchronize one object between two controllers in Cocoa

Tags: iphone, cocoa-design-patterns

I have a MainController, it creates an object(say polygon), a controller(say,polygonViewController).  PolygonViewController has two outlets:

```
IBOutlet Polygon* aPolygon;
IBOutlet UILabel* numOfSidesLabel;
```

it mediates Polygon and PolygonViewController.xib file.

How do I make sure the PolygonViewController's aPolygon is the same(instance) as polygon created in mainController?

I tried to add `@property Polygon* aPolygon;` to PolygonViewController then in MainController I did `polygonViewController.aPolygon = polygon;` However, aPolygon in PolygonViewController awakeFromNib method is always null.

Comment: Some code pieces would help here.... 
Why are you declaring an IB outlet for aPolygon when you are assigning it the mainController's Polygon object?
As such I don't there is a mechanism to make two Polygon objects declared in two different XIB files to be the same object.

Comment: Hi Deepak:
Thanks for your help.
The Polygon object in MainController is not prefixed with IBOutlet, so it is not in an XIB file. In general, what is the approach if i want to assign my controller class an object created in another class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use a singleton object?

You can make your aPolygon class to be a singleton object so, you will be always working with the same object in as many viewControllers as you want to use it.

Take a look at: http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32

Hope this will help you!

Cheers,
VFN

Comment: hi vfn:
this might be a possible solution. I would give it a go.
cheers